# How to get enums from restful GET

Tags: java, rest, enums

I have a simple restful service that return a vehicle. The vehicle contains Enums, and I should get them all to my client. I need the collection of enums for POST the specific vehicle. 
How is the best way to get the enums from restful service or is there a better approach for POST enums to service?

```
<vehicle>
  <year>1999</year>
  <power>358.0</power>
  <price>13084.0</price>
  <fuel>HIBRID</fuel>   <--ENUM
  <numberDoors>FIVE</numberDoors>   <--ENUM
  <GEAR>AUTOMATIC</GEAR>   <--ENUM
   ....
</vehicle>
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html. Parse the response, and use the `valueOf()` method to retrieve the right enum

Comment: I know how to use enums, but I don't know how to use them with restful services. I' know how parse the enum. I don't know how to POST enum if I don't know which are possible.

Comment: It's just a text string: an XML content element, or a JSON string

Comment: @extra90 Then there is something wrong. You can't use an API if you don't know the API.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Do you want to publish a schema so people know all the expected values?  Do you want to know how to use enums in your marshalling/unmarshalling bindings (ie: jaxb/jackson)?  Also, do you really want an enum where the possible values might change without a code release?

Comment: Yes but the client doesn't know all enums which are stored in the service. The client has to get the collection first.

Comment: @extra90 Then your service needs to have a method for obtaining that collection.

Comment: Tell the client through api documentation, which can be WSDL, WADL, or even a plain PDF explaining it.

Comment: @DMoses I' think is the best way to get schema so people know all the expected values. But I don't know how.

Comment: So it is just documentation API thing. Thanks for fast solution :)

Comment: Yep, UNLESS `gear` for example isn't an enum, but rather a set of all distinct gear types which may change.  If that is the case you should have an endpoint that returns all the gear types.  But if it's enums and release dependent, then documentation is what they will want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create several Enumeration(s) in the client, each of them describing the values for the different fuels, gears, etc.

Let's say you have this enumeration, which holds all the possible Fuel values:

```
public enum FuelTypes {
  DIESEL, HIBRID;
  //...
}
```

Then, by invoking `FuelTypes.valueOf("HIBRID")` you will receive the Object `FuelTypes.HIBRID`.

The static methods `valueOf()` and `values()` are created at compile time and do not appear in source code.